# Simple XML and custom list

Tags: java, xml, serialization, simple-framework

I try to serialize this class using the simple XML framework :

```
public class Div
{
  private MyFrameworkList< Div > _children = new MyFrameworkList< Div >() {{
    append( new Div( "a" ) );;
    append( new Div( "b" ) );;
    append( new Div( "c" ) );;
  }};

  // some methods and attributes...
}
```

To :

```
<div>
  <children>
    <div class="a">
    </div>
    <div class="b">
    </div>
    <div class="c">
    </div>
  </children>
</div>
```

`MyFrameworkList` is part of a framework and it doesn't implement `Collection` interface so it can't be annotated `@ElementList`. Unfortunately I can't fix the last point.

I tried to build a `Converter` but I don't find how to serialize list values.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to do this:

Implement a *Converter* for ...

1. ***`Div`*** class, so you can create the serialization of this class by your own - allowing you to fully customize your xml.
2. ***`_children`*** field only, so you can do the same as 1., but only for this single field - everything else is done default by simple.
3. ***`MyFrameworkList`*** class - similar to 2., but annotated for the class, so other instances everywhere around your code get serialized that way too.

I've already answered your other question, there you'll find an example of how to implement and use Converters in simple; please see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843221/simple-xml-and-hashset/20936067#20936067).

If you get stuck at any place, please report back and we'll fix your problem ;-)

Comment: If I choose to convert the children field only, how can I ask to process recursively div children ?

Comment: You implement a `Converter<MyFrameworkList<Div>>`, so the `write()` methods takes a `MyFrameworkList<Div>` as argument. To serialize *all* `Div`'s withing your list, you can use a Serializer / Persister in your Converter. This allows you to delegate the serialization of those objects back to Simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the list and create a String representation, similar to what we do with toString

Comment: Can you provide an example using the Converter interface?

Comment: @user2970188 can you provide the description (or a link to) of your Converter interface?

Comment: From the simple XML documentation : http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/Converter

Comment: @user2970188 Check here, i've implemented one for you at your 2nd question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843221/simple-xml-and-hashset/20936067#20936067